# Incorrect input parameters when using the Python Requests library

Tags: python, bash, curl

I have a Python script using the Requests library that is of this form:

```
uhash = '1234567abcdefg'

cookies = { 
    'uhash':uhash
}

payload = { 
    'action':'trade.bump', 
    'hash':uhash, 
    'tradeid':'12345678'
}   

r = requests.post(
    'http://www.target_url.com/api/core', 
    cookies=cookies, 
    params=payload
)
```

Above is my Python attempt at creating the following cURL request (written with bash):

```
HASH="1234567abcdefg"

TRADEID="12345678"

curl 'http://www.target_url.com/api/core' -H "Cookie: uhash=$HASH" --data "action=trade.bump&hash=$HASH&tradeid=$TRADEID"
```

In summary, both scripts contain:

1. The cookie - `uhash`
2. Three `data` parameters called `action`, `hash`, and `tradeid`

My issue currently is, the bash script works - the server response for when I use the bash script is this:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"bumped":true,"count":15}}
```

However, if I use the Python script, with the SAME cookie and parameter values as the bash script, I get:

```
{"meta":{"code":301},"data":{"message":"You can't bump a trade that doesn't exist ;_;"}}
```

The above error tells me the trade doesn't exist, despite that `tradeid` existing and the exact same one as my bash script's parameters.

I tried to debug using Firefox' convenient copy-as-curl tool to copy that curl command, which was how I made the bash script. However, once I tried to translate it to the Python script, it will tell me the aforementioned error. Maybe I am using the Requests library incorrectly, and I am missing something.

Attached is the full cURL request taken from Firefox (don't worry, the parameters were sanitized, meaning, they're not the real values):

```
curl 'http://www.tf2outpost.com/api/core' -H 'Host: www.tf2outpost.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: http://www.tf2outpost.com/trades' -H 'Cookie: __qca=P0-6517545-1420724809746; __utma=5135382.11011755.14224810.14331180.14180489.7; __utmz=51353782.1420724810.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); uhash=abcdefg12345678; mb_uid2=3211475230616776; CTag61=14338638870; __utmb=513532.9.10.14180489; __utmc=513782; __utmt=1; __utmt_b=1; __utmt_c=1; OX_plg=sl|qt|pm; HIRO_COOKIE=data=&newSession=true&id=2237524293&timestamp=1433506185; HIRO_CLIENT_ID=67751187' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --data 'action=trade.bump&hash=abcdefg12345678&tradeid=12345678'
```

Not quite sure why that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using data or json key instead of params, use json.dumps(payload) if data is your preferred method.

Comment: Aaaaaand this worked. I knew I was using the Requests library incorrectly! Mind if I ask what the difference between `data` and `params` is?

Comment: params is for GET-style URL parameters, data is for POST-style body information.